# mongoid 6.1.0 eager loading throwing weird error undefined method each for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, eager-loading

i have two basic mongoid classes:

```
class CaseType
    include Mongoid::Document

    has_many :case_type_field_sets

...


class CaseTypeFieldSet
  include Mongoid::Document
...
  belongs_to :case_type
...
```

in the console, I do something simple like:

```
CaseType.includes(:case_type_field_sets).count
```

this works fine.

If i do

```
CaseType.includes(:case_type_field_sets).first
```

it throws an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
from /(path)/lib/mongoid/relations/eager/base.rb:92:in `set_on_parent'
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is it specific to mongoid version? Did you try it with a previous version of mongoid?

Comment: thanks jagdeep for the answer.  i did look into this.  it turns out the issue was that i had declared the referenced _id field in the model.  Removing that resolved the issue. I will post an answer when I am allowed to, there's some stupid SO rule about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you manually declare the foreign key, which is a force of habit if you're building a mongo app after being in the habit of building a mysql app.  So if you have manual declarations like:

```
belongs_to :parent
field :parent_id, type: String
```

Removing that foreign key declaration, b/c mongoid takes care of this for you, will fix the "undefined method each for nil" issue.